# How do I convert an ISO8601 date to another format in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-format, datetime-format

Facebook outputs dates in ISO8601 format - e.g.:
2011-09-02T18:00:00

Using PHP, how can I reformat into something like:
Friday, September 2nd 2011  at 6:00pm

Nb - I was doing it in Javascript, but IE has date bugs so I want a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A fast but sometimes-unreliable solution:

```
$date = '2011-09-02T18:00:00';

$time = strtotime($date);

$fixed = date('l, F jS Y \a\t g:ia', $time); // 'a' and 't' are escaped as they are a format char.
```

Format characters detailed [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: strtotime is magical, but not omniscient. '01-02-03' will probably parse wrong, since it's utterly non-obvious which is Y, M, or D. In this case, the date string is a well-documented format, so not going to be an issue. But relying on strtotime to be always right is a bad way to go.

Comment: On testing - the 't' also needs to be prefixed with an '\' escape char.  (just in case anyone should ever have the same problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

#### Converting from ISO 8601 to unixtimestamp :

```
strtotime('2012-01-18T11:45:00+01:00');
// Output : 1326883500
```

---

#### Converting from unixtimestamp to ISO 8601 (timezone server) :

```
date_format(date_timestamp_set(new DateTime(), 1326883500), 'c');
// Output : 2012-01-18T11:45:00+01:00
```

---

#### Converting from unixtimestamp to ISO 8601 (GMT) :

```
date_format(date_create('@'. 1326883500), 'c') . "\n";
// Output : 2012-01-18T10:45:00+00:00
```

---

#### Converting from unixtimestamp to ISO 8601 (custom timezone) :

```
date_format(date_timestamp_set(new DateTime(), 1326883500)->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')), 'c');
// Output : 2012-01-18T05:45:00-05:00
```