# strtotime conversion

Tags: php

How do I format this str coming from a database to something more readable.

2012-04-06T10:55:58-07:00

I would like it in the format of  m-y.
I have tried

```
$date = date('m-y',strtotime('2012-04-06T10:55:58-07:00'));
```

I am stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: You should export from your database as a unix time stamp, or perform the date formatting as part of your query. mysql?

Comment: The data is coming from Microsoft crm. We are very limited in how we can bring back data.

Comment: You say you want it in the form of m-y, but in the function its y-m? What are you expecting the $date value to be?

Comment: The problem is you don't have a date/time string, but an interval, looking at the time part. Is every record an interval? You could choose to strip the last x characters, although it's not really reliable...

Comment: @Tom, ok what are you expecting $date to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the time zone isn't meaningful you can chop it off like this:

```
$dbDateString = '2012-04-26T10:55:58-07:00';
$dateString = substr($dbDateString, 0, 10);
$date = date('m-y',strtotime($dateString);
```

or you can go the cheap route:

```
$dbDateString = '2012-04-26T10:55:58-07:00';
$year = substr($dbDateString, 0, 4);
$month = substr($dbDateString, 5, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out: [How do I convert an ISO8601 date to another format in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458585/using-php-how-convert-an-iso8601-date-to-a-different-format)

They solution they provided was:

```
$date = '2011-09-02T18:00:00';

$time = strtotime($date);

$fixed = date('l, F jS Y \at g:ia', $time); // 'a' is escaped as it's a format char.
```