# php - date format ISO 8601

Tags: php, date, time

I have encountered this date format:

```
2013-03-12T09:16:12.1550656+01:00
```

from what I have found in net this is ISO 8601 (am I correct?).

How can I convert this this date format using php?

I can generate it easily using date('c'), but I need convert this type of date:

```
20130422122037 - (YYYYMMDDHHMMSS)
```

Comment: see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: This question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458585/using-php-how-convert-an-iso8601-date-to-a-different-format

Comment: this is one of the formats that [`strtotime()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) understands, just use that

Comment: Why was my edit removed? if it is iso 8601, the seconds part can only be 2 chars long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$date = new DateTime('20130422122037');

var_dump($date->format('c'));
```