# Ebay API ISO 8601 duration format to timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, ebay-api, iso8601, dateinterval

Ebay API provides me time in ISO 8601.

For example, it gives me item time left: **P0DT0H1M4S**
Here is how this time is formatted: [ebay duration](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/types/simpleTypes.html#duration)

I want to convert this time to simple Y-m-d H:i:s format. 
So far I've tried `date("Y-m-d", strtotime("P0DT0H1M4S"));` but it does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using PHP: How convert an ISO8601 date to a different format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458585/using-php-how-convert-an-iso8601-date-to-a-different-format)

Comment: Maybe not, the date format in that question doesn't use the duration format like in your example.

Comment: @MikeB: I've already seen this question, no luck :(

Answer (score 3):

That date interval string is [an ISO 8601 duration specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso8601#Durations) and can be use with [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P0DT0H1M4S'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

or as a one-liner (PHP 5.4+)

```
echo (new DateTime())->add(new DateInterval('P0DT0H1M4S'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JXY4rq)